# jquery exclude if child has span with certain class?

Tags: jquery

I have this Chrome Extension, it adds a poke all button under your pokes.  I am trying to update it so when you have 6 pokes or more, the "Show All (6)" makes it refresh My poke all button. [because it disappears when you click on the "Show all (6)"]. So in my code this is how I add the button:

`$("#pagelet_pokes a:last").after(html_code)`

so in facebook there is a div with the id="pagelet_pokes", it has tons of sub divs, and eventually there is a div w/ class='phs', with a , and in that list are the poke links.

So to simplify:

```
<div id='pagelet_pokes'>
...
<div class='phs'>
<ul>
<li><div><div><a href>Poke #1</a></div></div></li>
<li><div><div><a href>Poke #2</a></div></div></li>
</div>
</div>
```

So jQuery adds my button, after the last . That works fine.

The problem is, the "Show all (6)" adds another <li> at the bottom, and when clicked, it hides itself instead of removing it [display=none]. so after the above code, it adds:

```
<li class='showAll'>
<a href='#'>
<span class='fwb'>Show all (6)</span>
</a>
</li>
```

Now, I tried changing my code in my javascript to this:

```
 $("#pagelet_pokes a:last").not('.showAll').after(html_code)
```

It did not work, because, the first selector selects all the <a>s, then discards any a's that have .showAll, but that doesn't help because the .showAll is in a child node!

So my question boils down to this..  How do I select the last "a" within #pagelet_pokes, that does **not** have a child span with the class "pokeAll"?  Is there some "!" selector that might work like this? : `$('#pagelet_pokes !li.showAll a:last')`? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`not-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

```
$('#pagelet_pokes li:not(.showAll) a:last')
```

Or to make your selector valid for `querySelectorAll` *(used internally when possible)*:

```
$('#pagelet_pokes li:not(.showAll) a').last()
```

---

**EDIT:**

I can't quite tell from the question, but if that last `li` that you want to exclude is *always* there, then I'd be inclined to keep the selector simple, and use the [`slice()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method on the result:

```
$('#pagelet_pokes li a').slice(0, -1);
```

Comment: May also be faster to do this: `$('#pagelet_pokes').find('li').not('.showAll').find('a').last()`.  I've found splitting up the selectors have improved performance in a lot of places, not always though.

Comment: dw, the problem is, sometimes the li is there, sometimes is is not.  [Depends on if the person has 6/+ pokes] I need the selector, to match the last *poke*, no matter what is there. @Anthony, this seems to select the last poke, but, I need to be able to operate on the element, with .after() or .css(). It doesn't seem to work.. [using Chrome's JS console]

Comment: I finally decided to use another anchor, because even though your code worked [for the most part], if I put in your code, it would not work if you did not click the "Show all (6)" link...